# WinApi - Get Monitor Index on which a process is running

Tags: windows, winapi, multiple-monitors

I am building an application on which I am launching browser processes to specific URL's. I need to know after the browser is launched on which monitor the process started ( monitor 0-based index). I haven't found something straightforward to do this so my approach is the following:

- launch browser with ShellExecuteEx
- get processId from shellexecuteinfo
- get window handle from process
- get monitor from window handle
- get monitor info
- enum display devices and detect index

My approach works for firefox and chrome, but only when the browser is launched for the first time. If the browser is already launched and a new tab is opened instead, the process id returned by shellexecute doesn't have a window.

My code is :

```
if( !ShellExecuteEx( &info ) )
    {
        ShowMessageBox( errStartBrowserFailed );
    }

    HWND windowHandle = NULL;
    DWORD processId = GetProcessId( info.hProcess );

    while( windowHandle == NULL )
    {
        windowHandle =  FindWindowFromProcessId( processId );
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    HMONITOR monitor = MonitorFromWindow( windowHandle, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST );

    MONITORINFOEX monitorInfo;
    monitorInfo.cbSize = sizeof( MONITORINFOEX );
    GetMonitorInfo( monitor, &monitorInfo );

    DWORD   displayIndex = 0;
    DISPLAY_DEVICE  DisplayDevice;
    DisplayDevice.cb = sizeof( DISPLAY_DEVICE );

    // get all display devices
    while( EnumDisplayDevices( NULL, displayIndex, &DisplayDevice, 0 ) )
    {
        if( wcscmp( monitorInfo.szDevice, DisplayDevice.DeviceName ) == 0 )
        {
            break;
        }
        ZeroMemory( &DisplayDevice, sizeof( DISPLAY_DEVICE ) );
        DisplayDevice.cb = sizeof( DISPLAY_DEVICE );
        displayIndex++;
    }
```

In case the browser is already launched windowHandle will always be null and I guess that the processId isn't a real process since I can't find it in Task Manager.
    Does anyone know a solution for my problem or has any other approach i might follow ?

Comment: [ShellExecuteEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154.aspx) has no control over opening a file in a new tab. This is implemented by the application itself. A common implementation would be for an application to check, whether another instance is already running, and if so, have that other application open the new tab, and then exit. This could explain, why your new process doesn't own any windows.

Comment: What do you want to do with the index if you find it? And what do you think it means? For example, the monitor indices shown in the control panel don't necessarily correlate with the order retrieved by `EnumDisplayDevices`.

Comment: Processes don't need to have windows. Processes can create multiple windows. Those windows can be on different monitors. Or stretch over multiple monitors. I think before you go on you probably need a clearer picture of how these concepts relate.

Comment: I already have all monitors, retrieved before using the same function, so they are in the correct order. Since, as mentioned, with ShellExecuteEx I can't control to much what the browser does, I need to know at least the monitor index on which it started after ShellExecute function returns even if it is a new tab or the browser started for the first time. My app logic is related with monitor calibration so it is important to know the monitor on which you see what is opened in the browser.

Comment: Going to be close to impossible to do this in general for arbitrary applications

Comment: It appears that the handler you executed detected that another copy was already running and handed the request to that other process. You will need to use app-specific techniques to find that other process. Perhaps Firefox and Chrome offer an API that lets you get the information you need. (IE does, but that doesn't help you here.)

Comment: Why not just pick a browser that you want to support and ditch ShellExecute entirely. Or use one of the browser controls that come bundled with Windows ([ex. MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040.aspx)) so you have full control.